# GeoServer Image Pyramid extension returns faulty image

Tags: gdal, geoserver, mbtiles, image-pyramids

I have a set of mbtiles files for a basemap from https://daten.gdz.bkg.bund.de/produkte/topplus_open/TopPlusOpen/aktuell/mercator/ which I want to serve as a WMS-Service via the image pyramid extension. These files include 18 zoom levels with 1 zoomlevel per file with zoomlevel 0 as the lowest zoom (whole world) and 18 the highest zoomlevel where the individual zoomlevels have individual styles and labels (see image 2 and 3).

For this I have:

1. downloaded the datasets
2. clipped the mbtiles to a given extent with a shapefile (`gdalwarp -cutline path/to/shapefile.shp -crop_to_cutline -dstnodata 0 xx.mbtiles xx_clip.mbtiles`)
3. converted the mbtiles for each zoomlevel into GeoTiff for each zoomlevel via gdal (`gdal_translate -of GTiff xx_clip.mbtiles xx_clip.tiff`)
4. retiled the GeoTiff for each zoomlevel (`gdal_retile -v -ps 4096 4096 -co "TILED=YES" -co "COMPRESS=JPEG" -targetDir zoomlevel\xx xx_clip.tiff`) and saved it into the required folderstructure for the pyramid extension (pyramidfolder/zoomlevel 0-x)
5. created a new datastore (image pyramid) with the default settings and published it with the default settings as well (the grid datasets as well as the property files are generated for each zoomlevel and the entire pyramid folder)

The result of the GeoServer preview looks like this:

---

[image]

---

[image: zoomlevel 7]

Zoomlevel 7

---

[image: zoomlevel 6]

Zoomlevel 6

GeoServer is running as a docker container and the extensions are installed as descriped [here](https://docs.geoserver.org/main/en/user/installation/docker.html). The steps 1-4 execute without errors and the tiffs in QGIS look as they should. Any suggestions what I am doing wrong here?

Data source of the images: © Bundesamt für Kartographie und Geodäsie (2023), Datenquellen: https://sgx.geodatenzentrum.de/web_public/Datenquellen_TopPlus_Open.pdf

Comment: where did `xx_clip.tiff` come from?

Comment: Hi Ian, thanks for your response. The xx_clip.tiff is the result of the clipped and converted mbtiles. I edited my question.

Comment: I think you need to stick all the tiles together at the highest zoom level and then create the pyramid from that - use a VRT

Comment: The zoomlevels provided by the linked homepage comprise different labels and styles based on the individual zoomlevels. These individual styles and labels I want to preserve. I have added two zoomlevels to my question to show what i mean. When I compute the pyramid from the highest zoomlevel I guess I would lose the styles and labels. Is there a way to build the pyramid and preserving the individual styles and labels?

Comment: Then `gdal_retile` is the wrong tool for the job - it splits up a single image and creates overviews of it.

Comment: thank you for your responses Ian, I really appreciate them. What would be your approach to serve these mbtiles with 1.8 TB as a WMS while preserving the zoomlevels and the information they are holding?

Comment: That I can't say - I wouldn't start with mbtiles to be honest - don't they provide a WMS or WMTS endpoint

Comment: They do provide both, a WMS and a WMTS, but the mbtiles are the only format for the download. In our case we have to rebuild the WMS in order to meet our response time and failover requirements